# Convert string like '{x:=1, y=2, z=3}' to JSON in python

Tags: python, json

I want to convert the string `'{x:=1, y=2, z=3}'` to a Python object. I tried `json.loads()`, but got an error, it was expecting string to be `'{"x":1, "y":2, "z":3}'`.

I'm new to Python, if anyone can help that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may want to try to parse the string yourself:

```
def parse_input(x):
    result = dict()
    x = x.replace(":", "")
    for pair in x[1:-1].split(","):
        key,value = tuple(pair.split("="))
        result[key.strip()] = int(value.strip())
    return result
```

Alternatively, you can convert the string to be valid json and then load it:

```
obj = json.loads(data.replace("{", '{"').replace(":", "").replace("=", '":').replace(", ", ', "'))
```

If you want an evil solution that "works", here you go:

**However, only use this, if the input is 100% trusted (as it uses eval).
Also, this will only work for inputs exactly matching your example.**

```
obj = eval(data.replace("{", "{'").replace(":", "").replace("=", "':").replace(", ", ", '"))
```

Comment: Note: Don't use eval against untrusted input. For example, try `eval('{\'x\':__import__(\'os\').listdir()}')`

Comment: (I know you have already discussed trusted inputs in your answer, but why use `eval` when so many safer (and just as easy) options exist? Write a regex. Or read the string character-by-character and write your own logic to parse out the integers (or other data). Or, as your answer includes: split() by space or other separator and then split again by `=`. In each of these cases,  you can use a safer method such as `int` to evaluate the input, and all that can happen is an error is thrown, which you just have to catch and handle appropriately.

Comment: `eval` is _almost_ never the right answer. IMO the part after "if this is not what you are looking for" should be the primary focus of your answer. Other than the `eval` part, this is a good answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: You are right that `eval` should not be used for any untrusted input. I changed the primary answer to the other option.
Still, I think `eval` and `exec` can be very useful tools for fast and hacky solutions that are only used once on trusted data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, btw I did this - 

`import json
data = '{x=1, y=2}'
y = json.loads(data.replace('{', '{"').replace('=', '":').replace(', ', ', "'))`